# Unexpected bevel output

Tags: modeling, objects, bevel

I'm trying to bevel a curve with another curve.

I've been using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2SIbAxLftc
and was successful with my first few attempts like this:
[image]

I'm redesigning the curve now though and trying to bevel the curve again but am getting a weird output that doesn't follow the curve path at all and doesn't match my first attempts.

Here are the new curves (highlighted one is the path, the other is the bevel shape):
[image]

And the output when beveling:
[image]

I've tried changing the orientation and dimensions of the bevel shape with no success. I've also tried the different curve spline types for both.

It seems like there is a weird offset. You can kind of see where it's following a similar path, but much wider than it should be.

I'm all out of ideas of what could have gone wrong and hope someone sees this that can help.

[I'm attaching a blend here that also includes the original curve after its been converted to a mesh.](https://mega.nz/#!3RcjmIKa!va-_d6WLYC3w_ECiaNc-HXkkkgwpL8Xfh-AdS5bjNgU)

Update: I loaded an old saved blend and tried applying the bevel again and it worked fine. <strike>So I think my problem is solved, but if anyone has an idea what could have caused the issue I would like to hear it so I can avoid making the same mistake in the future.</strike> After making a new curve in the old blend file I'm seeing the same issue. The only global blender changes I can think that I've made since the last successful bevel was curve add-ons. Going to go through that list until I find the culprit.

Update: Solved: The issue turned out to be the scale factor of the path curve. Applying a scale reset before beveling fixed the issue.

Comment: Solved: The issue turned out to be with the scale factor of the path curve. Not sure how but the scale got changed, so applying a scale reset fixed the problem.

Comment: Hello :). Can you please post it as a full answer? Comments can get deleted. Thanks :).